# Location of textView returning 0,0

Tags: android

I have two `textView` objects, one of which is `"@+id/touchView"` and the other is `"@+id/viewLocat"`. I would like `viewLocat` to display the coordinates of `touchView` when the activity starts.

This is what I have done so far (in my `.java` file):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        View touchView = findViewById(R.id.touchView);
        TextView viewLocat = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.viewLocat);
        int[] viewLocation = new int[2];
        touchView.getLocationOnScreen(viewLocation);
        viewLocat.setText(String.valueOf(viewLocation[0]) + "x" + String.valueOf(viewLocation[1]));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

However, when I start the activity, the value in the textView is `0,0`.

I also tried another approach, shown below (also in the `.java` file):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        View touchView = findViewById(R.id.touchView);
        TextView viewLocat = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.viewLocat);
        viewLocat.setText(String.valueOf(touchView.getTop()));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

However, this simply returns `0`. **How can I make the code return the coordinates of the `TextView` in relation to its parent `LinearLayout`**

Comment: Is `touchView` located on the top left corner of the screen?

Comment: Yes it is, which is why I thought it would make sense. However, I then tested it by moving `touchView` down by adding a `View` above it, but it still returned 0,0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view won't return the correct information until it has been laid out.